# add wookmark layout after angularjs data bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

i am trying to add wookmark layout plugin in my angularjs app but i can't

my controller code -

```
pb.controller('category_mobile', function($scope, $http, $window, $location) {
      $scope.onload = function() {
$scope.paramUrl = $location.url();
$scope.paramUrl = $scope.paramUrl.replace(/^.{1}/,''); 
$scope.apiurl = $scope.apiurl+$scope.paramUrl; 
if ($scope.paramUrl) {
  $http({method: 'GET',url:$scope.apiurl}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.productData = data.deals; 
    $scope.qitem = data;  
  });
}
else 
{
  $http({method: 'GET', url: $scope.url}).success(function(data) {    
    $scope.productData = data.deals;       
  });
}
```

};
    });

How i add my  wookmark code in angularjs onload function . My wookmark jquery code -

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
 setTimeout(function() {
 (function ($){
   var handler = $('#tiles li');

   handler.wookmark({          
      autoResize: true,
      container: $('#main_pro_content'), 
      offset: 11, 
      outerOffset: 0, 
      itemWidth: 200,
      fillEmptySpace: true
     });     
   })(jQuery);
 }, 1000);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

There is no Angular onready event. That line of code would also not pick up new elements added to the page after the document is ready, such as loading a template.

The correct approach would be to make wookmark a directive and specificly apply it to the element you want it on.

```
module.directive('wookmark', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            JQuery(element).wookmark({          
                autoResize: true,
                container: $('#main_pro_content'), 
                offset: 11, 
                outerOffset: 0, 
                itemWidth: 200,
                fillEmptySpace: true
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Then on your element add the 'wookmark' attribute.

I have dealt with wrapping JQuery widgets within angular directives before and if you need 2-way binding from the widget you should get or make a pure angular implementation to save yourself massive headaches in the future.